# mongodb get all documents but only specific sub document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have documents like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed79a6750869a5738e679c2"), 
    "SerialNumber" : "867688034502264", 
    "sharing":[ 
      { from:"abc", to: "123"},
      { from:"123", to: "435"}]
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed79a6750869a5738e679c3"), 
    "SerialNumber" : "867688034502111"
}
```

i would like to get all documents and in sharing field i only want to get subdocuments where "from" has a specific value like "abc"

i would like to get:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed79a6750869a5738e679c2"), 
    "SerialNumber" : "867688034502264", 
    "sharing":[ 
      { from:"abc", to: "123"}]
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed79a6750869a5738e679c2"), 
    "SerialNumber" : "867688034502111", 
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Aggregation Pipeline`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) with a [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      SerialNumber: "$SerialNumber",
      sharing: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$sharing",
          cond: {
            "$eq": [
              "$$this.from",
              "abc"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/n41uUeDdv9Q

Note that it will set `sharing` to `null` if the property is missing. If that's an issue, you can further filter the document before filtering, or you can do another `$project` as a separate stage.

Answer (score 0):

You and use [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#db-collection-find) with [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html#elemmatch-projection) in the projection:

```
db.collection.find({}, {SerialNumber:1, sharing: {$elemMatch: {from: "abc"}}})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xQ7fEorMfJB)